# UITextField text not appearing at the center

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am just using a `UITextField` and the problem is the text in the `UITextField` do not appears at the **center**.It is placed at the top position of my textField.Is there any default settings that i am missing out.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Vertically or horizontally centered?

Comment: Use this UITextField *txtField;
txtField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

Comment: I need Vertically centered

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For vertical alignment:

```
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

Centered both vertically and horizontally:

```
theTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
theTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Centered within the parent container:

```
YourTextFieldName.center = parentViewField.center;
```

Comment: Use UITextAlignmentCenter instead of UITextAlignmentCenter in iOS 60.0+.

Comment: I think you want to say `NSTextAlignmentCenter`

Comment: @MichaelPeterson Guess we'll have to wait 47.5 years for that

Comment: for swift v5.0, both `centerVerticalAlignment` and `textAlignment` should be `.center`

Answer (score 15):

Constant `UITextAlignmentCenter` is now deprecated as of iOS6 and above.

You should use:

```
textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4:

```
// vertical alignment
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = .center

// horizontal alignment
textField.textAlignment = .center
```

Answer (score 1):

**For swift**

To align vertically use

```
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
```

To align horizontally use

```
quantity.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

This one line code works perfectly to me